# Datatables search box not taking inputs after updating

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatable, datatables

Code to initialize datatable,

```
jQuery('#table1').dataTable({
  "scrollY": "200px",
  "scrollCollapse": true,
  "paging": false,
  "aaSorting": [],
  "oSearch": {
    "bSmart": false
  }
});
```

Filter working perfectly when the table is initialized at first. When table data is updated using ajax call, search box freezes(it's not taking any input). datatable update Code,

```
var table1 = jQuery('#table1');
result = [];
if (data.length) {
  jQuery.each(data, function(key, value) {
    json = ['<span id="hexa" class="' + value.carrier_code + '">' + value.company_web_name + '</span>', value.city, value.state];
    result.push(json);
  })
}
//console.log(result);
table1.dataTable().fnClearTable();
table1.dataTable().fnAddData(result);
table1.dataTable().fnDraw();
```

here 'data' is returned from ajax call. sorting works fine, but search input box not taking any input after the table is being updated(works fine when loaded for the first time).

Comment: no error in console when you add new data??

Comment: nope, console showing no error after updating

Comment: so strange.... just for test try do define table1 = jQuery('#table1').dataTable({ when you initialize the table  ...... then call table1.fnClearTable(); table1.fnAddData(result); table1.fnDraw();

Comment: didn't work. Just so you know, there are multiple datatables in that page, and input box stops working for all the datatables when any one of them is updated

Comment: make sure the tables ve different ids... then try to keep uncommented only one table and try if it work

Comment: tables have different ids, otherwise it should have generated errors when the page loads for the first time.

Answer (score 0):

Always create a reference to your dataTable while initializing, like below.

```
var table1 = $('#example').dataTable({...});
```

From now on, you can use the variable `table1` for future references, such as clearing/adding/drawing table. Take a look at the demo below.

```js
var table1 = $('#example').dataTable({
    "scrollCollapse": true,
    "paging": false,
    "aaSorting": [],
    "oSearch": {
        "bSmart": false
    }
});

var result = [];
for ( var i=0; i< 10; i++ ) {
    var json = [
        '<span id="hexa" class="cc' + (i+1) + '">My Company ' + (i+1) + '</span>',
        "City" + (i+1),
        "State" + (i+1)
    ]
    result.push(json);
}

table1.fnClearTable(); // No dataTable() here
table1.fnAddData(result); // No dataTable() here
table1.fnDraw(); // No dataTable() here
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/datatables/1.10.7/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/datatables/1.10.7/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<table id="example" class="display" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Position</th>
            <th>Office</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    
    <tfoot>
        <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Position</th>
            <th>Office</th>
        </tr>
    </tfoot>
    
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>Tiger Nixon</td>
            <td>System Architect</td>
            <td>Edinburgh</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Garrett Winters</td>
            <td>Accountant</td>
            <td>Tokyo</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Same result as before. Sorting works after table is updated but can not enter any text in search box.